# Strange caching problem for API and DB on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2012, windows-server

Has anyone else had issues when trying to update a website in an application pool and the changes don't seem to be reflected at all when navigating to the URLs.

I'm a dev working in a development to user acceptance testing to then production environments. I'm currently trying to upload a asp net core api and react app to a Windows Server 2012 server. The API communicates with an isolated sql sever. I have a dev-sql db and a uat-sql db.

Are there any Caching features that I might be overlooking that are causing these problems?

I've definitely updated appsettings.json & the environment variables to reflect the UAT database and API but... it still acts as if it's looking at the DEV database and dev API.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you publish your site after dong changes?  after publishing, you need to open iis and refresh the site[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxmw3.png). to disable the cache in iis you could use the HTTP response header feature. select HTTP reasons header feature Click on the set common header link from the action pane.
Click the checkbox "expire web content" and select "immediately" radio button [image2](https://i.imgur.com/UJ1vi44.png)

Comment: make sure you assign the right user permission to access the database.